# How to convert a differential equation into a certain form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we convert a first order linear differential equation $$\dot{y}+p(t)y=q(t)$$ into an equation of the form $$\dot{y}=k(t)y$$?

Comment: See the integrating factor method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor to solve such an ODE.

Comment: that will give me the solution. But i want to convert one differential equation into the other.

Comment: Then you can't. See @Henning Makholm'S answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not with the same $y$. The particular equation $\dot y=1$ ($p$ identically zero, $q$ identically one) cannot be expressed as $\dot y = k(t)y$.

Comment: That's right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = g(t)$ is one solution of $\dot{y} + p(t) y = q(t)$, then the transformation $y \to y + g$ takes solutions of $\dot{y} + p(t) y = 0$ to solutions of $\dot{y} + p(t) y = q(t)$ and vice versa.

Comment: -Actually I am trying to find the conditions on $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ for the solution $y(t)$ of the differential equation $$\dot{y}+p(t)y=q(t)$$ to be periodic. Here i assume that the coefficients $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are periodic in time.

Comment: Why don't you ask your real question, then?